# How to export a fingerprint template using Windows Biometric Framework (WBF)?

Tags: c++, windows, frameworks, biometrics

I'm implementing an application that uses biometric identification to sign documents. To do that I need to enroll a biometric template for every user and store it in the application database.

Studying [WBF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/dd401509(v=vs.85).aspx) I'm not finding a way to recover this template to store in my application database. Anybody has ever made something like that?

Thanks.